# How do I get the OSGi BundleContext for an Eclipse RCP application?

Tags: java, osgi, eclipse-rcp

I have just gotten started with an Eclipse RCP application, it is basically just one of the provided "hello world" samples.

When the application boots up, I would like to look at my command-line parameters and start some services according to them. I can get the command-line parameters in *IApplication.start*:

```
public Object start(IApplicationContext context) {
   String[] argv = (String[]) 
       context.getArguments().get(IApplicationContext.APPLICATION_ARGS)));
}
```

But how do I get the BundleContext, so that I can register services? It does not seem to be in the IApplicationContext.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Tricky internal way:

```
InternalPlatform.getDefault().getBundleContext()
```

could do it.

You will find an example in [this class](http://www.koders.com/java/fid303B02634E3F752520A89254E5DC13BE4BD68639.aspx?s=eclipse+IApplicationContext++BundleContext#L11)

```
public class ExportClassDigestApplication implements IApplication {

    public Object start(IApplicationContext context) throws Exception {
        context.applicationRunning();

        List<ExtensionBean> extensionBeans = ImpCoreUtil.loadExtensionBeans(&quot;com.xab.core.containerlaunchers&quot;);
        for (ExtensionBean bean : extensionBeans) {
            ILauncher launcher = (ILauncher) bean.getInstance();
            launcher.start();
        }
        ClassFilter classFilter = new ClassFilter() {
            public boolean isClassAccepted(Class clz) {
                return true;
            }
        };
        
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter( new File( "C:/classes.csv"));
        
        Bundle[] bundles = InternalPlatform.getDefault().getBundleContext().getBundles();
```

---

[Proper way](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform/msg41088.html):

> Every [plug-in](http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/runtime_model_bundles.htm) has access to its own bundle context.
>
> Just make sure your plug-in class overrides the [start(BundleContext)](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v41/org/osgi/framework/BundleActivator.html#start%28org.osgi.framework.BundleContext%29) method. You can then save it to a place classes in your plug-in can easily access
>
> Note the bundle context provided to a plug-in is specific to it and should never be shared with other plug-ins.

Comment: But the `start` method itself requires a bundle context: where would you take that to feed your `BundleActivator` ? I can take it from `FrameworkUtil` but that (in my case) is `null` so... Otherwise you declare your activator in the MANIFEST, so I get a bundle context.. but how was it given to it? :)

Comment: @Campa not sure: that was 6+ years ago, and I don't have access to that kind of project anymore. You can ask a new question with a link back to this one though.

Comment: InternalPlatform.getDefault().getCommandLineArgs(); helped me to get the eclipse headless build command line arguments.

Answer (score 14):

Just came across this doing a web search, and thought I'd promote the new standard OSGi R4.2 way (as provided by Equinox shipped with Eclipse 3.5).  If you don't have an activator, and don't want to create one just to cache the bundle context, you can use FrameworkUtil.getBundle.  Modifying the previous example:

```
import org.osgi.framework.FrameworkUtil;

public class ExportClassDigestApplication implements IApplication {
    public Object start(IApplicationContext context) throws Exception {
        context.applicationRunning();
        BundleContext bundleContext = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(this.getClass())
                                                   .getBundleContext();
    }
}
```

Comment: Caution here, the bundle context might not exist for the bundle in some OSGi implementations. It's not required to be there.

Comment: @Francis: Here is a lucky one! My bundle provides no context (`null`). Other alternatives? (Internal tricky hacks are good not)

Comment: It seems that a plugin declaring a `Bundle-Activator` will have its context set, otherwise `FrameworkUtil`-way will return `null`.

Comment: And even with this internal hack, you'll be in trouble if you want to inject an Eclipse `IEventBroker` in your class: @see `Unable to process "EventBroker.logger"` error.