# Loading plugin from a JAR file

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I'm having a requirement to put a plugin (with UI) in a JAR. From another plugin UI (via eclipse menu) I need to show the UI of the plugin in the jar. Is it possible? I mean dynamically loading another plugin programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

Something like this:

```
BundleContext bundleContext = Platform.getBundle("your-plugin-id").getBundleContext();
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
String name = "initial@" + file.toURI().toURL().toString();
Bundle b = bundleContext.installBundle(name, is);
b.start();
```

But I dont think this is what you want to do. Just create a dependency between the Eclipse plugin to the JAR file. Then when the user clicks the menu and the action is triggered, you just start the UI from the jar file as you would normally do.

Comment: Thank you very much. Do i need to create a dependency between the Eclipse plugin to the JAR file for your code to work? The Plugin JAR file I'm mentioning is downloaded from a database once the user selects the plugin description in a list box. So we cannot create a dependency right?

Comment: @user3544081 If the plugin is not available at build/compile time, you cant create a dependency. The code example above just needs a file to install it.

Comment: Is there any requirement for the get bundle context (line 1 of sample code you provided) to be successful. I'm getting NullPointerException if I closed the plugin (the JAR one) project.

Comment: @Kumar NPE means that the bundle isn't found. It hasnt been resolved, that is, its not available or a dependency prevents it from loading. You may want to split it to two lines, first "Platform.getBundle("your-plugin-id")" and check that it doesnt return null.

Comment: Thanks for reply. "Platform.getBundle("your-plugin-id")" is returning null. I feel there is no dependency problem, since it worked before when the project (the JAR one) was opened in workspace. If the plugin to be available or resolvable for this method call then what I need to do? I mean without opening the project in the work-space. If any other information is required for you to answer please let me know.

Comment: @Kumar Probably a dumb thing to ask, but you are changing the string "your-plugin-id" with the actual id of the plugin, right? The string needs to be the exact same id as that of your plugin. Look it up in installation details in help-about menu if you are unsure.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion (I just copy-pasted from your comment). Yes I've given correct plugin id. The thing is i must not restart Eclipse or open the plugin project in-order to install the plugin. The JAR or plugin is not known to eclipse until I install it programitically

Comment: You use the id of the plugin you have installed, you wrote " another plugin UI (via eclipse menu)". This is a backwards way of doing thing, since you will install the jar into the plugins bundlecontext. I'm unsure of the consequences, but it does work. 
An alternative of getting ahold of a bundlecontext object is described here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559989/how-do-i-get-the-osgi-bundlecontext-for-an-eclipse-rcp-application

Comment: I tried both of them as below. Failed to stop the bundle by throwing BundleException. 1) bundleContext = InternalPlatform.getDefault().getBundleContext();    2) bundleContext = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(this.getClass())            .getBundleContext();

Comment: Sorry @Kumar I can't really help you any further... The issue seems to be more complicated to solve than what can be done in a forum like this.